# How to tell if a class is Spring loaded in java?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have been given a task to assign a property from `.properties` file to a **non Spring** bean class using **`@Value`** annotation. To do this, I created a method on a **`@Component`** annotated class and set the property into it, then called that method from the non Spring bean class. I thought this would work, however, still showing as null.

I was told this is because the **`@Component`** annotated class I used is not spring loaded. Question, how can I tell if a class is Spring loaded bean? I have been searching on google but can't find anything helpful aside from examples with **`@Component`** or **`@Configuration`** annotations. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the sample code snippet ?

Comment: is this a spring boot application ?

Comment: You'll have to configure Spring so that it finds the `@Component` annotated class and then look it up in the Spring application context. If you instantiate the class with `new MyClass()` then it's not managed by Spring and dependencies and things like `@Value` fields will not be filled in.

Comment: See: [Why is my Spring `@Autowired` field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: You have to enable component scanning in Spring, so your classes annotated with `@Component` will be instantiated by Spring and registered as a Spring bean in the Spring application context. Dependecy injection with the `@Value` annotation will only work if the target object (where the value should be injected) is a true (managed) bean. Other than that and your injected properties/method params etc. will always be null!

Comment: Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Container is responsible for creating or managing beans. It all satisfy the dependencies by injecting them either through constructor or setter method. But in your case you want the @Value injection in your non spring bean which is really not possible as per my understanding. Because here the spring does not creating the object then how it satisfy the dependencies of it.

You have two options for this situation.

1. Either annotate class using @Component
2. Either read property file using `Properties`

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/